# How gravitational time dilation affects free-fall time

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation, free-fall

Consider a point-like planet having a large mass $M$ and two small point-like objects with masses $m_1<m_2$.

Drop down each of them separately from distance $d$ on the planet, let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the times until they collide with the planet, respectively (those can be approximated by using Kepler's Third Law).

In Newtonian mechanics, we could say that $T_1=T_2$, since the planet will not accelerate (because of its large mass), and the acceleration of the two objects will be exactly the same (since it only depends on $M$). BUT the planet will also accelerate towards the objects (its acceleration will be extremely small, but positive), slightly faster in the second case (because of $m_2>m_1$).

That makes $T_1$ slightly bigger, than $T_2$ (**increases $T_1-T_2$**).

The same train of thought would apply when dealing with general relativity but in this case, gravitational time dilation would also affect $T_1$ and $T_2$. The mass difference $m_2>m_1$ causes more curved spacetime in the second case and therefore slows the time more for any observer.

That effect increases $T_2$ slightly more than $T_1$ (**decreases  $T_1-T_2$**) (because $m_2>m_1$ causes more curved spacetime in the second case and therefore slows the time more for any observer).

Since both the difference of the planet's acceleration and the difference of the speed of time are extremely small (and are opposite effects since one increases, and the other decreases $T_1-T_2$), I do not know intuitively which has a stronger effect on the relation of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

I see that the answer may strongly depend on $\frac{M}{m_2}$ (the answer may be different in the two extreme cases: $M\approx m_2$ and $M\gg m_2$), and the location of the observer, so the final question(s) would be:

**Does the object having mass $m_2$ always* collide with the planet in a shorter time than the lighter one or not?**
If not, what is the condition?

* : for any $M,m_1,m_2,d$ and any possible observer

(As a high school student, I do not have the necessary level of knowledge to do exact calculations, please forgive me if the question is trivial or meaningless...)

Comment: The Newtonian case is nicely covered in the top Related question below, *Don't heavier objects actually fall faster because they exert their own gravity?*

Comment: The first thing you have to specify when talking about time in relativity is time *relative to whom*. Are these T1 and T2 times measured by a distant observer? (In which case gravitational time dilation is irrelevant.) Or are they the proper times measured by the two objects themselves?

Comment: I modified the question and tried to specify it better. I meant to ask if there is a case in which (for a specific observer, for example near the planet) the lighter object falls down in a shorter time than the heavier? Or equivalently: the time dilation affects the falling time more than the acceleration of the planet (or do these effects have incomparably different magnitude)?